# Magento product catalog not showing

Tags: magento2.3, cache

I am running Magento 2.3.3 and I an issue with product catalog images not showing both on frontend and adminhtml.

I have seen that it is a common problem, but I tried all recommended solutions, but nothing worked.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US he_IL --language en_US --language he_IL
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I also tried to rename `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` to _cache.

When I tried `bin/magento catalog:image:resize` I am getting this error on all images:

```
Cannot resize image "/home/mysite/public_html/releases/20201220114403/pub/media/catalog/product/5/1/5113-g.jpg" - original image not found
```

I think that this is related to this bug in core magento, that apparently was fixed in 2.3.4:
[magento catalog:images:resize now Database Media Storage mode aware (Again!)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/23913)

I am pretty sure that images exists on disk and database (how can I test this?), just that magento is stuck on old cache and is not refreshing.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?